# Everyone Will Like This For Sure!

Tags: rebus

1.

[image]  [image]

  2.

[image] [image]

Note :

> The title is a hint for **number 1 only**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Number 1 is probably

> Starbucks (shooting star + bucks).

Number 2 could be

> Paypal? (pay + pals)

Title:

> Who doesn't like Starbucks? (actually I don't drink coffee so maybe the title's wrong.)

Comment: Lol, the first on makes much more sense :D

Comment: Wow, all correct! Ahh, I made this one too easy again :D @Riley

Answer (score 1):

Could number 1 be

> Falling/raining money. Meter shower(rain), money.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not right. Although I do believe everyone will like falling money :D